# Mailing issue in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I have a script and it's causing some problem. But before that I want to state a file-structure regarding my server.

If I directly upload my scripts under the `www` folder then there is no problem. But if I create a folder named `ecommerce` under my `www` folder and then I put the script, then it's throwing the problem.

Say I have created a folder `www/ecommerce` the the mailing is having the problem.

Here's my script

```
$this->load->library('email');
            $config['charset'] = 'utf-8';
            $config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
            $config['mailtype'] = 'html';
            $config['protocol'] = 'sendmail';
            $this->email->initialize($config);
            $this->email->from('info@divinotech.com', 'Divinotech Support');
            $this->email->to($email);
            $this->email->subject('Welcome To SaiBoutique');
            $msg="<div align='center' style='background-color: #cfcfcf; width: 400ox; height: 300px;'><strong>You Have Been Successfuly registered to SaiBoutique.com. Please Visit Our Site To Have Fabulous Offer</strong>
                  <br/>
                  <br/>
                  <a href='".base_url()."user/activate_account/".$activation_key."'><strong>Click Here To Activate Your Account</strong></a></div>";
            $this->email->message($msg);
            if($this->email->send())
                echo "Successfully Registered' Please Log-In.Mail Send To Your Email-ID";
```

I am writing this inside a controller.

I need to keep it in `www/ecommerce` such that my project link will be like this:

```
http://divinotech.com/ecommerce
```

Here's the error code

```
Exit status code: 127
Unable to open a socket to Sendmail. Please check settings.
Unable to send email using PHP Sendmail. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.
User-Agent: CodeIgniter
```

Comment: **some problem**, **having a problem** will not help us to help you until you describe the problem in detail. Also, it looks like you have not properly set the base_url

Comment: my base_url is accurately set up its set as http://divinotech.com/ecommerce/

Answer (score 0):

(1) If you are using shared hosting, Most of the shared hosting companies disable "sendmail" for security purpose. Check with your hosting provider about "sendmail".

(2) If you are using VPS or dedicated server, then you can check "sendmail" is working properly in your server with help by server admin.

(3) Other immediate solution is to use SMTP to send mail.